# CORS, политика безопасности

Tags: javascript

Создал расширение для Chrome, и оно работало.
Решил переделать это расширение в сайт.
Встал вопрос о такой ошибке:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

В Chrome есть файлик `manifest.json`, в котором можно было сделать так:

```
"permissions": [
    "http://name.ru/*",
  ]
```

И проблема решалась, но как решить эту проблему на локалке не знаю.
Запрос выглядит так:

```
    function start () {
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "http://name.ru", true);
    xhr.send(null);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) 
        {
            if (xhr.responseText) 
            {
              // тут функции
            }
        }
   };
```

Доступа к сайту я не имею, расширение брало с него инфу для работы.

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/120336/

Comment: без доступа к сайту вы эту проблему не решите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблему решила cURL.
Через jQuery я обращаюсь к PHP. На PHP с помощью cURL сделал запрос, и отправил на нужный мне сайт.
Получаю ответ на jQuery, и работаю с ним.

```
<?PHP 
$q = $_REQUEST["q"];
$ch = curl_init($q);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
$text = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```